# Solving nfs "Stale file handle" caused by server reboot

Tags: nfs, nfs4

This is a follow-up question to 
["Stale NFS file handle" after reboot](https://serverfault.com/questions/617610/)

as its solution doesn't work for me.

My case is simple, after server rebooted, I'm getting "`Stale file handle`" on client side, even after

- I umount all nfs mounts and remout them on client side. or,
- On the NFS server UN-export and re-export the file system

I can control both end (and don't mind kill/restart anything), what's the simplest solution to overcome the above situation?

Comment: I would assume that the simplest solution is to restart the clients.  Is that ruled out in your scenario?

Comment: Yeah @HarryJohnston, I gave up and restart the client machine. And to my greatest surprise, I'm still getting "Stale file handle" on client side, despite that both server and client have now been restarted.

Comment: Which filesystem is exported by the server? Does the client application uses locks?

Comment: The filesystem on both side (client & server) are both ext4. I don't think  locks are used, because I'm actually sharing nfs4 as RO. Further it's the mpv the movie playing program that I used to access nfs4, which I believe is read-only and don't think it place any locks. Thanks @kofemann